# NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: repeats:NO selector method calls multiple times

Tags: iphone, nstimer, uialertview, nsthread

I am using NSThread along with NSTimer.

My code is like this

```
-(void) checkForRecentAlarm
{
    if ([self.alarmThread isFinished]) 
     {
        [self.alarmThread cancel];
     }
    self.alarmThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startTimerForRecentAlarm) object:nil];
    [self.alarmThread start];
    //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startTimerForRecentAlarm) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
-(void)startTimerForRecentAlarm
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    self.recentAlarmTime = [NSDate date];
    self.dbObject = [[RADataBaseModelManager alloc] init];
    self.recentAlarmTime = [self.dbObject getMostRecentAlarmTimeFromDB];
    if (self.recentAlarmTime) {
        NSTimeInterval timeIntervalToAlarm = [self.recentAlarmTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
        NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
         //Fire timer every second to updated countdown and date/time
        self.RATimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeIntervalToAlarm target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [runLoop run];
    }
    [pool release];
}
 - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    [self.RATimer invalidate];
    [theTimer invalidate];
    self.RATimer = NULL;
    theTimer = NULL;
    [self playAlarm];
    UIAlertView *alarmAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alarm" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Snooze", nil]; 
    [alarmAlert show];
    [alarmAlert release];
    alarmAlert = nil;

}
```

Now the problem is, my alertbox comes twice for one call in the
    startTimerForRecentAlarm 
method. So that the alert comes consequently twice and my view get stuck.

What will be problem here?

I am trying to implement an alarm with multiple alarm option using a single NSTimer.

Please help.

When I debug this, I can find many simultaneous threads are running on same code(UIAlertView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any obvious reason why that would be called twice, but it does seem like an overly complex way of doing what you need to do.

Have you thought about using [local notifications](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html)?

If you don't want to do that, you could refactor your code so it works like this:
1. Add a new event
2. If there's no timer or the time to the event is shorter than the time on the timer, then set the timer for this event.
3. When a timer fires, check for the next event and set a timer for that event (if there is one).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please suggest me some code block so that I can implement the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

This does seem really complex. My general observation is that if you get two timer firings it's because you have two timers for some reason.

If you have multiple threads doing UIAlertView, you have another problem, because you can only (reliably) do UI from the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please suggest some code so that I can do this with less complex. Please because I am a fresher in iPhone application development.

Comment: I haven't coded local notifications, but they seem like the perfect way to do alarms. (And they can do something when your app isn't running.) Or, if you have n different alarms, create n different NSTimers. I see no need to try to use just one timer. Bottom line, avoid threads unless you absolutely need them, because threaded code is always hard to get right.

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement streaming from internet as my alarm tone. I have the following assumptions, If I am wrong, Please correct me.....      1) local notifications - when alertbox comes, user has to tap on the button to open the application and play stream. But for me it should be played automatically.    2) n different NSTimers will slow down the application UI navigation.     3) Without threads the application UI is just get stuck when the Timer starts.

Comment: If this only has to work when your app is open, create any number of NSTimers you need. With `-initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` you can set them for when you need them to go off. They aren't going to take any time until they do. And there's nothing to prevent you from doing the actual work in a thread (though better to abstract that with NSOperation or GCD) once the timer fires.